# Use ELCImagePickerController to pick video

Tags: ios

I am trying to pick video by `ELCImagePickerController` from photo library, but when I print this

```
NSLog(@"%@",[dict valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaType"]);
```

it returns `ALAssetTypeVideo` , not a **public.movie** type,

I have no idea is there any way to pick a movie(like .mov) from `ALAssetTypeVideo` ?

sorry , My English is not very good :')

Answer (score 6):

Change `ALAssetsGroup` filter to `allAssets` in `ELCAlbumPickerController.m` file:

here:

```
 ALAssetsGroup *g = (ALAssetsGroup*)[assetGroups objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [g setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
```

and here:

```
[picker.assetGroup setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
```

Answer (score 3):

We need to replace "allPhotos" with "allAssets" in ALAssetsFilter at
    two place to show all asset (including video ) in ELCImagePickerController code
    as given below

**First change :**

```
ALAssetsGroup *g = (ALAssetsGroup*)[assetGroups objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
[g setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter **allAssets**]];
```

**Second :**

In tableView `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method

```
[picker.assetGroup setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter **allAssets**]];
```

But video asset thumbnail will be same as image thumbnail  , to change  it write custom code in `ELCAsset.m` class  constructor `initWithAsset:(ALAsset*)_asset`

**For example :**

check

```
if ([self.asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] == ALAssetTypeVideo ){
                 // code for video thumbnail 
      }

if ([self.asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] == ALAssetTypePhoto ){
             // code for Photo thumbnail 
    }
```

Comment: To increase the quality of your post please include how/why your answer will solve the problem.