# How to select multiple video from camera roll and photo Gallery?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to upload multiple video to server using ASIHttDataFormRequest.For selecting video ,I am using ImagePickerViewController But it doesn't give the option to select multiple video.

Bellow is the code, which is used to open imagePicker and but unable to select multiple video.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Please help me by giving some clue or code. Thanks in Advance

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/assetlibrarymultiselect

Comment: Using Assets library.

Comment: How to get video url using ELCImagePickerController

Answer (score 1):

Use this sample

https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController

For video multiple selection refer

[Use ELCImagePickerController to pick video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931779/use-elcimagepickercontroller-to-pick-video)

Hope it helps you..

Comment: *Your inputs are really appreciated but just providing links to tutorial site or Github does not really make a good answer. Please post them as comments.*

Comment: Thanks for Reply.But there is any way to select multiple video using imagePickerViewController.

Comment: How to set restriction on ELCImagePickerController for selecting only video not any image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the library to take a photo or select from library: https://github.com/fulldecent/FDTake

This works great so far for photos. Video is in progress.

Comment: *Your inputs are really appreciated but just providing links to tutorial site or Github does not really make a good answer. Please post them as comments.*

Comment: Thanks for Reply.But I want to upload multiple Video

Comment: @KDRocks you can customize this control as per your requirement as photo select you can change to video also